# Joining a table in mysqli and then fetch the matched result

Tags: mysql, sql

i am having two tables in my DB like members and payments . Table Members has the name and id of users and payment table has the id,amount and session of payments like if user 1 has paid 1500 for a session 3 then table payment has the following details. mid 1, session 3 and amount 1500.

Now i want to fetch the names of all the users which have not aid for session 1

i am using the following query but it is not working

```
SELECT NAME
    ,id
FROM member m
    ,payment p
WHERE (
        p.session = '3'
        AND m.id != p.mid
        )
```

This is not giving me the required result please help me .

Comment: What about `select m.name, m.id from member m join payment p on m.id != pm.mid where p.session=3`?

Comment: @Tamar should be `=`, not `==` (this would be php syntax, not sql).

Comment: mid and pid has the user id , i think if its not same then we get the names of not paid users ..

Comment: use table alias with `name,id` and `on m.id == pm.mid` kind of join condition is missing

Comment: @chris85 its not working !!

Comment: What happens, error, no result, too many results?

Comment: @chris85 too many results

Comment: The problem is that your query lists those users, whose id do not match the id of a payment record for session 3. You will get all users back, some multiple times. This question is basically, give me list of users, who do not meet a certain criteria in a joined table. You can do this via left join, not in, or not exists.

Comment: The linked duplicate demonstrates both the not exists and the not in solutions. In your case, probably the not exists is the fastest, since you do not want any data from the payments table.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
SELECT NAME
    ,id
FROM member m
    inner JOIN payment paid
    ON m.id = paid.mid
        AND paid.sessionid = '1'
LEFT JOIN payment p
    ON m.id = p.mid
        AND p.sessionid = '3'
WHERE p.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

When you want to get data from more than 2 tables , you have to use join and if you don't want to use join as you are doing, then make sure you have exact relation between that tables, e.g a.id = b.membe_id etc..
And in your case, i think the relation is not right, make sure you have something common in two tables.

Thanku.

Comment: id in mem and mid in payment is common

Comment: You have to use alias with column names. 
SELECT m.name
    ,m.id
FROM member m
    ,payment p
WHERE (
        p.session = '3'
        AND m.id != p.mid
        )